# Ajax filter not returning page content with filter

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, filter

I have a special function on some of my pages that returns a modified embed code. It works great:

```
    if (/*is_page() &&*/ has_category('Krajské zprávy')) {
        /* get subtitle */
        $subtitle = apply_filters( 'plugins/wp_subtitle/get_subtitle', '', array(
           ) );

        if ((strpos($subtitle , 'kraj') == false) && (strpos($subtitle , 'Praha') == false) && (strpos($subtitle , 'Vysočina') == false)) {
            $subtitle = "Všechny kraje";
        };

        /* get page id with embed code */
        $id_short = 357;
        $tag_id = array (
            'Ovzduší' => 357
        );
        foreach ($tag_id as $k => $v) {
            if (has_tag($k)) {$id_short = $v;}
        }

        /* get embed code & replace */
        $acf_kod = get_field('embed_kod', $id_short /*,false*/);
        $replace_sub = "<param name='filter' value='Parameters.Kraj="  . $subtitle . "'>";
        preg_match_all('/<param [^>]*>/', $acf_kod, $matches);
        $m_1 = $matches[0][0]; $m_2 = $matches[0][1];
        $pos = strpos( $acf_kod, $m_1) + strlen( $m_1 );
        if (strpos($acf_kod,$m_2)-(strpos($acf_kod,$m_1)+strlen($m_1))<2) {
            $before = substr ($acf_kod, 0, $pos);
            $after = substr( $acf_kod, $pos, strlen( $acf_kod ) );
            $whole = $before . $replace_sub . $after;
            $content = $whole .'<!--more-->' . $content;
        };
    /*echo $whole;*/
        };
    return $content;
};
add_filter('the_content', 'add_embed_parameter');
```

However, I also have a filter on my site that filters pages by categories and tags and returns them via Ajax. That, too, works just fine - but only with "standard pages" that don't use the code above. For the pages that do, it returns nothing.

This is a snippet of the php code that is used by the filter:

```
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            /*$content = get_post_field( 'post_content', get_the_ID() );*/
            $content = get_the_content (/*get_the_ID()*/);
            $content_parts = get_extended( $content );
            echo '<h2>' . $query->post->post_title . '</h2>', 
                            $content/*$content_parts['main'] /*'<p>' . $query->post->post_excerpt . '</p>'*/;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
```

This is the whole AJAX thing (it's not mine, I'm using the tutorial [here](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html)):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Any idea where the problem might be? Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about wordpress, but did you check if the ajax call hass the right url and data. And try to console.log() the response. Also try to use xdebug in your IDE you can better see what is going on during a request.